# Connect RFC 2217 laser via LAN - Python

Tags: python, sockets, ethernet, lan, rfc2217

I'd like to communicate with a laser system through an application created with Python. Up to now, I tried to use `socket`, but without any success.

I only have access to these infos from the laser manual.
[laser manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxKVl.png)

Below the non-working test code I wrote

```
import socket
laser = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
laser.connect(("169.254.0.1", 10001))
laser.settimeout(1)
laser.send("STATE/r/n".encode('ascii')) # check the state of the laser (internal command)
time.sleep(10)
out = laser.recv(1024)
print(out)
```

Any idea?

Comment: 1) this is just standard networking: do you know the IP address actually is 169.254.0.1 once it's on your network - if so you'll likely have to change your PC's IP address to be on the same subnet - better to go into the setup of the laser device and make it use DHCP to get a network address, and then look at your router to find the assigned address, and 2) a TCP socket isn't the same thing as telnet protocol - you need to use a telnet client like telnetlib to connect to the device's (correct) IP address. Finally, what is the full error message you get - edit it into the question.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try your solution and I'll let you know (at least on thursday because we have restrictions due to covid). I don't see any error, simply I don't receive any response and the program stops after one second, probably due to the timeout setting.

Comment: So the `socket.connect` line doesn't give an error. You could try changing to a different port like 1025 - if this also doesn't give an error then something else is wrong because you should get an error if the IP+port isn't listening. You should also try connecting using commandline telnet and type the same command. (not literal \r\n, just press enter). Good luck.